# Can you give one directory two SELinux Policies?

Tags: selinux

Out of laziness I want to be able FTP into my WWW directory.

However, the SELinux permissions for apache(user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t) to be able to use the WWW directory and for the user(system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t ) to use the WWW directory are different.

Anyway, around this problem without disabling SELinux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a third file context and add it to both domains.

Comment: Actually showing how to do that would be provide a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the httpd_enable_homedirs to true. See
http://diegobz.net/2010/03/07/enabling-apache-userdir-public_html-with-selinux-enabled-on-fedora/
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache

(assuming you're on Fedora)